# Why does Kotlin has secondary constructor and init block?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin has primary and secondary constructors and init block. We can not execute any code in the primary constructor. Because of this Kotlin provides an init block which executes the code inside just after the instance is created.

I couldn't find any problem that can't solve with primary and init block.
I don't think it's about any performance issue.

My question is why do we have a secondary constructor and why we should use a secondary constructor?

Comment: You can't find any cases where you might want to have two constructors that accept different sets of parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's for cases where you might want to pass different parameter types to the constructor.

For example, suppose you have a class representing a person and their birth month. The birth month is represented with the Month enum class. But it might be convenient to sometimes use the numerical representation of the month as an Int.

```
data class Person(
    val name: String,
    val birthMonth: Month
) {

    constructor(name: String, birthMonth: Int): this(name, Month.of(birthMonth))
}
```

Or if you're building a tree, it might be convenient to be able to have the option to automatically add the node to its parent when creating it:

```
class Node(
    val name: String
) {
    val children = mutableListOf<Node>()

    constructor(name: String, parentNode: Node): this(name) {
        parentNode.children.add(this)
    }
}
```